# Not Printing Average

Tags: c, file, debugging, io, syntax-error

I have a project going in two files, but I cannot get the main program to print out the average variable, I just get 0.0 no matter what I change. It also does not print out a whole other function Any Tips?

```
Main File:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
float average(void);
float std_dev(float);
float output(float);

float  array[10]  =  {4.8,  12.98,  82.1,  5.98,  19.75,  24.9,  75.7,  3.45,  10.0,  28.11};
extern float avg;
int main()
{
 float s = 0.0;
 printf("The average value of the array is %.2f \n", avg);
 s = std_dev(avg);
 printf("The standard deviation of the array is %.2f \n", s);
 return 0;
} 

static void output(float var)
{
    printf("The value of the variable is %.2f \n", var);
}
```

Second File:

```
#include <math.h>
extern float array[];
float avg = 26.78;

static float average()
{
    int n;
    float sum = 0.0, mean=0.0;
    for(n=0; n<10; n++)
        sum = sum + array[n];
    mean= sum/10;
    output(mean);
    return mean;
}
float std_dev()
{
int n;
float cumm_diff = 0.0;
for(n=0; n<10; n++)
     cumm_diff += (avg -array[n]) * (avg -array[n]);
return sqrt(cumm_diff/10);
}
```

Comment: It's curious that you spend your efforts to use `float` instead of `double`, but then use `sqrt()` instead of `sqrtf()`.

Comment: You should avoid parameterless functions when possible.  Your code would be more general (reusable) if you passed the array as length plus pointer to start (e.g. `float std_dev(size_t num_data, float data[])`.

Comment: After getting the program to compile (there are compilation errors e.g. the declaration and definition of `output()` differ), The `avg` variable prints just fine.

Comment: The posted code contains LOTS of `double` literals.  In all cases, they should be `float` literals.  To make them `float` literals, append a `f` to the end of each of the literals.

Comment: regarding: `static void output(float var)`   The idea behind using the `static` modifier is that the function will not be visible outside of the current file.  Suggest changing the statement to: `void output( float var )`  Then in the second file insert the statement: `extern void output( float );`

Comment: this statement, in the first file: `float average(void);` is useless.  However, it is needed in the second file written as: `float average( void );`

Comment: regarding: `s = std_dev(avg);`  the variable `avg` is visible in the second file, and the use of a parameter does not match the prototype,  Suggest replacing the statement with: `s = std_dev();`

Comment: overall, there should be a header file for each of the two source files,  And each of the source files should be including each of those header files.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. demonstrates how to execute functions in external files
4. properly prototypes the functions
5. removes extraneous code
6. properly formats the code for ease of readability and understanding
7. eliminates the 'magic' numbers
8. lets the compiler determine how many items are in the array
9. uses `float` literals rather than `double` literals
10. documented why each of the system header files is included
11. used meaningful parameter and variable names
12. derived the value of `count` at compile time
13. cast the `int count` parameter, when needed, to a `float`

and now the proposed code:

header file: main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
void output(float var);
extern float avg;
#endif // MAIN_H
```

header file: util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H
float calc_std_dev( float *, int  );
void  calc_mean( float *, int );
#endif // UTIL_H
```

main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include "main.h"
#include "util.h"


float  array[]  =
{
    4.8f,  12.98f,  82.1f,  5.98f,  19.75f,
    24.9f, 75.7f,   3.45f,  10.0f,  28.11f
};



int main( void )
{
    printf("The average value of the array is %.2f \n", avg);

    float s = calc_std_dev( array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(float) );
    printf("The standard deviation of the array is %.2f \n", s);

    calc_mean( array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(float) );
    return 0;
}


void output(float var)
{
    printf("The mean value of the array is: %.2f \n", var);
}
```

util.c file

```
#include <math.h>  //sqrtf()
#include "main.h"
#include "util.h"


float avg = 26.78f;


void calc_mean( float array[], int count )
{
    int n;
    float sum  = 0.0f;
    float mean = 0.0f;

    for(n=0; n<count; n++)
        sum = sum + array[n];

    mean= sum/ (float)count;
    output(mean);
}


float calc_std_dev( float array[], int count  )
{
    int n;
    float cumm_diff = 0.0f;

    for(n=0; n<count; n++)
         cumm_diff += (avg -array[n]) * (avg -array[n]);

    return sqrtf(cumm_diff / (float)count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call your function `average()`, which is why the average is not computed, but the initialized value `avg = 26.78` (not 0 - you probably changed that at some point) is printed and used by `std_dev()`.